# FoundationDB - inserting data through key-value layer and reading it though SQL-layer. Is it possible?

Tags: foundationdb, nosql

I'm trying to use FoundationDB for some specific application, thereby I'm asking for some help about the issue i cannot resolve or find any information about.

The thing is, in the application, I MUST read the data through the SQL layer (specificly, the ODBC driver). Nevertheless, I can, or even I'd prefer, to insert the data with the standard key-value layer (not through the SQL layer).

So the question is - is it possible? Could you help me with any information or at least point me where to look for it (I failed to find any brief info by myself)?

I belive that inserting the data through the SQL layer is probably less efficient which seems pretty understandable (since the DB itself is no-SQL), or maybe I am wrong here?

Let's not focus about the reasonableness of this approach, please, as this is some experimental academic project :).

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though you asked not to, I have to give a big warning: **There be dragons down this path!**

Think of it this way: To write data that is always as the SQL Layer expects you *will have to re-implement the SQL Layer*.

Academic demonstration follows :)

Staring table and row:

```
CREATE TABLE test.t(id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, str VARCHAR(32)) STORAGE_FORMAT tuple;
INSERT INTO test.t VALUES (1, 'one');
```

Python to read the current and add a new row:

```
import fdb
import fdb.tuple
fdb.api_version(200)
db = fdb.open()
# Directory for SQL Layer table 'test'.'t'
tdir = fdb.directory.open(db, ('sql', 'data', 'table', 'test', 't'))
# Read all current rows
for k,v in db[tdir.range()]:
    print fdb.tuple.unpack(k), '=>', fdb.tuple.unpack(v)
# Write (2, 'two') row
db[tdir.pack((1, 2))] = fdb.tuple.pack((2, u'two'))
```

And finally, read the data back from SQL:

```
test=> SELECT * FROM t;
 id | str
----+-----
  1 | one
  2 | two
(2 rows)
```

What is happening here:

- Create a table with keys and values as Tuples using the STORAGE_FORMAT option
- Insert a row
- Import and open FDB
- Open the [Directory](https://foundationdb.com/documentation/api-python.html?highlight=directory#directories) of the table
- Scan all the rows and unpack for printing
- Add a new row by creating Tuples containing the expected values

The key contains three components (something like `(230, 1, 1)`):

- The directory prefix
- The *ordinal* of the table, identifier within the SQL Layer [Table Group](https://foundationdb.com/layers/sql/documentation/GettingStarted/table.groups.html)
- The value of the PRIMARY KEY

The value contains the columns in the table, in the order they were declared.

Now that we have a *simple* proof of concept, here are a handful reasons why this is challenging to keep your data correct:

- Schema generation, metadata and data format versions weren't checked
- PRIMARY KEY wasn't maintained and is still in the "internal" format
- No secondary indexes to maintain
- No other tables in the Table Group to maintain (i.e. test table is a single table group)
- Online DDL was ignored, which (basically) doubles the amount of work to do during DML

It's also important to note that these cautions are only for *writing* data you want to access through the SQL Layer. The inverse, *reading* data the SQL Layer wrote, much easier as it doesn't have to worry about these problems.

Hopefully that gives you a sense of the scope!